# symfony 2 csrf selective enable?

Tags: forms, symfony, csrf

I'm writing a backend app that has internal authentication of requests, so I don't need CSRF - except for a small number of forms that are actually exposed to the user.

So I've disabled CSRF in config.yml but I want to enable it for specific forms. According to the docs, this should do the trick:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // FIXME: this doesn't work, I still don't get CSRF ?
        'csrf_protection' => true,
        'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
    ));
}
```

but it doesn't, I still don't get a CSRF token in this form. My twig file says:

```
<form action="{{ path('mypath') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <button name="submit">{{ 'register.submit'|trans }}</button>
</form>
```

So that should work, too. What's the problem?

Comment: Could you post the twig file? Usually CSRF is missing because if in your form template you choose to not use the default form behavior `{{ form_widget(form) }}` you must put `{{ form_rest(form) }}` to get the token

Comment: added above. I do use the default.

Comment: What version of Symfony do you use?

Comment: 2.3.5 (fresh install)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you disabled CSRF in config.yml, you said that you don't want  CSRFExtension to be loaded in your project. You have just disabled it "in a global way". So you can't use it after that.

You can see in the code how it is done here: 
`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\FrameworkExtension::registerFormConfiguration($config, ContainerBuilder $container, XmlFileLoader $loader)`.

You can see, in your case this line returns false.

```
$this->isConfigEnabled($container, $config['csrf_protection']) // this returns false
```

And so CSRFExtension was not loaded.

If you did not get what relation between config.yml and extensions, read how it works here:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand what the problem is. Now how do I solve it? Can I enable the extension for a particular form, or do I have to globally enable it and then disable CSRF for every other form (I'd hate to do that, there are many more forms that don't want CSRF)?

Comment: Thanks. I still need to ask more - I don't want it enabled inside one bundle. I really need CSRF for maybe 3 or 4 forms and all other forms, even within that bundle, don't.

I might be mis-using forms as I use them in a client-server communication where the client knows how the form is built and basically submits it without ever requesting it.

Comment: I was not right that extension will be loaded in only one bundle. If you will use services.xml as I wrote, this extension will become available for ALL bundles.. So this solution does not suit you at all and I delete it from my answer. I can't solve this as you want and am not sure that it is possible to find a nice solution here... sorry.